# oracle client 11g for windows 7, there are no files that call "prereq" and "refhost.xml"

Tags: windows, oracle, oracle11g

I need oracle client 11g for using Toad.
My OS is windows 7.
To install oracle client 11g, I downloaded it from oracle site.
When i installed that, there was error that didn't install.
So I searched solution, and found it.

http://msutic.blogspot.kr/2009/08/how-to-instal-oracle-client-11g-on.html

But the problem is that there is no file that call "prereq" in stage folder.

I attach capture my situation.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHIdh.jpg)

how can i find "prereq" folder? 
I downloaded "win64_11gR2_client.zip" from oracle site.

Comment: Marko's article is quite old and the solution applies to 11gR1. Obviously Oracle changed things for R2. You will have to poke around and see what files you have. This is (part of) the price of using old software.

Comment: Also, which edition of Windows 7? Instant Client requires Pro, Enterprise or Ultimate

Answer (score 0):

Almost everything that needs an Oracle 'client' can use [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/).

You just need to know whether the application requires the 32-bit or 64-bit client.  Then download the 'Basic' package and unzip it.  Add the directory to PATH.  On Windows you will also need the correct VS Redistributable from Microsoft installed.  These are given on the Instant Client download pages, or use `dumpbin /dependents oci.dll` to find which Microsoft redistributable library is needed by your version of Instant Client.

Some applications may require other configuration, and/or Oracle header files. The headers are in the Instant Client SDK package.